# Looking for a Cellular network environment or Heteregenous wireless networks environment Datasets

Tags: discussion, data-request

I am looking for a Cellular network environment or Heterogeneous wireless networks environment Dataset. A dataset that includes network parameters as features such as delay, jitter, throughput, cost fo network ...etc.

Comment: Sorry stevGates we mistakenly migrated your valid question to Meta, and do not seem to have any way to move it back. Unfortunately the only solution seems to be for you to post it again at https://opendata.stackexchange.com, would you mind doing so? My apologies again for our error! :'-(